# Python replace particular substring in string

Tags: python

I need my program to replace a certain `-` with a variable. I've tried this but it replaces the whole thing with the varibale.

```
jelenleg = 8 * "-"
x = 0
guess = c
jelenleg = jelenleg[x].replace("-", guess)
print(jelenleg)
```

So I need this to happen:
before: `--------`
after: `c-------`
But instead what I get is this: `c`

Comment: @charelf omg how didnt i think of that thanks so much :)

Comment: Happy I could help! Also as a suggestion for the future, try maybe using a bit more descriptive titles, makes it easier to find answers! And if someone gives you the answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: @charelf :) Sorry Im a student I started programming a month ago so Im still learning a lot (including stackoverflow) :) Thanks again

Comment: No problem, we all started somewhere, have fun programming and using Stack overflow:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the count of to be replaced items:

```py
jelenleg.replace("-", guess, 1)
```

will only replace one `-`

To replace at a particular location, I can't think of anything easier than transforming the string into a list, then replacing, then back to a string, like this:

```py
jelenleg_list = list(jelenleg)       # str --> list
jelenleg_list[x] = guess             # replace at pos x
jelenleg = "".join(jelenleg_list)    # list --> str
```